# Why do I need to explicitly clear sessionStorage when using Cypress?

Tags: angular, session-storage, cypress

I am using Cypress to test an Angular application that pages through a list of doctors. The controller stores the current page in $sessionStorage.pagination. If I don't explicitly clear the session storage between tests, tests that follow my "should go to next page" test fail.  If I do explicitly clear the session storage between tests, everything works as expected.  This contradicts what I read here (https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/686) which seems to say that the session storage is automatically cleared between tests.

Is this a bug in Cypress? Or, am I misunderstanding what the Cypress developers mean by clearing session storage between tests?

```
describe('Simple Search Results Page Tests', function () {

    beforeEach(function(){
      cy.server();

    // routes omitted for brevity 

    // Changing pages breaks tests if I visit page under test like this
    cy.visit('http://localhost:9001/pageUnderTest'); 

    // tests work as expected if I visit page under test like this
    /*
    cy.visit('http://localhost:9001/pageUnderTest', 
              {onBeforeLoad: (win) => { win.sessionStorage.clear()}
    });
    /*
  }); 

  it('should search Best Match', function(){
    cy.get('[data-cy=first-name]').first().should('have.text', 'Michael')
      .get('[data-cy=last-name]').first().should('have.text', 'Emiley')
    });

  it('should go to the next page', function(){
    cy.get('[data-cy="page-number"]').click('right')
  }); 

  // this test is broken if session storage not explicitly re-set.
  it('should search Best Match (again)', function(){
    cy.get('[data-cy=first-name]').first().should('have.text', 'Michael')
      .get('[data-cy=last-name]').first().should('have.text', 'Emiley')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This [open gitlab issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/413) seems to match your issue and confirms it's a requested feature.

Reading through though, [this epic is mentioned](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/686), which states that Cypress does clear `sessionStorage`. So I'm a bit lost as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with context?

```
context('test 1', function () { cy.setCookie('test') })
context('test 2', function () { cy.getCookie('test').should('not.exist' })
```

does it exist?

Comment: unrelated answer